# Register gym environment that is defined inside a jupyter notebook cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, openai-gym

I'm trying to register an environment that has been defined inside a cell of a jupyter notebook running on colab. My problem is concerned with the entry_point. Some module has to be specified before the colon. But how do I know the module's name of the underlying colab notebook? Is there some workaround to wrap my custom environment inside a module without moving the code to another file? I'd prefer to have everything inside the entire notebook.

```
try:
  gym.envs.register(
      id='myenv-v0',
      entry_point=':MyEnv',
      max_episode_steps=320
  )
except:
    pass
```

If I call gym.make("myenv-v0")

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'
```

The try block is due to the fact that an evnrinoment id cannot be registered twice. It may happen that I run again all notebook cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After writing this question I finally figured out the right key words to conduct a proper search to find the solution.

The underlying module name can be retrieved using

```
import sys
sys.modules[__name__]
```

Therefore the module's name for the entrypoint is "**main**".

```
try:
  gym.envs.register(
      id='myenv-v0',
      entry_point='__main__:MyEnv',
      max_episode_steps=320
  )
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

`__main__` did not work for me, however, what I discovered was that you can also just pass in the class constructor into the `entry_point` argument like so:

```py
class MyEnv(...)...

register(
    id="my-v0",
    entry_point=MyEnv,
)
```