# Is it possible to run a custom OpenAI gym environment entirely from within Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, openai-gym, openai-api

**Long story short**: I have been given some Python code for a custom openAI gym environment. I can successfully run the code via ExperimentGrid from the command line but would like to be able to run the entire experiment from within Jupyter notebook, rather than calling scripts. This would be more convenient for some experiments that I will be doing farther down the road.

**My question**: Is it possible to execute an experiment on a **custom** OpenAI gym environment entirely from within Jupyter Notebook and if so, how? I've seen plenty of examples of people executing gym's standard environments (like SpaceInvaders-v0 or CartPole-v0) from Jupyter but even then, they are calling the environment with

```
env=gym.make('SpaceInvaders-v0')
```

and essentially executing that environment's script behind the scenes.

Below is a basic description of how my code is set-up to run from the command line and the errors that I'm getting in Jupyter.

Any advice would be appreciated. I am admittedly rather new to Gym, Python and Linux.

**My basic environment code** is structured like this in, say, envs/mygames/Custom_Env.py:

```
various import statements (numpy, gym, pyglet, copy)
class Entity()
class State()
class The_Custom_Env(core.Env) # This is the main environment class
class Shell_Class # This class calls The_Custom_Env and provides some arguments
```

In mygames/__ init__.py,I import the Shell_Class:

```
from gym.envs.mygames.Custom_Env import Shell_Class
```

In envs/__ init__.py, I have the environment registered

```
register(
id='TEST-v0',
entry_point='gym.envs.mygames:Shell_Class', 
max_episode_steps=200,
reward_threshold=25.0,)
```

Finally, if I execute a script containing this code from the command line, the experiment works without issue:

```
from spinup.utils.run_utils import ExperimentGrid
from spinup import ppo_pytorch
import torch

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--cpu', type=int, default=4)
    parser.add_argument('--num_runs', type=int, default=1)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    eg = ExperimentGrid(name='super-cool-test')
    eg.add('env_name', 'TEST-v0', '', True)
    eg.add('seed', [10*i for i in range(args.num_runs)])
    eg.add('epochs', [10])
    eg.add('steps_per_epoch', 4000)
    eg.add('ac_kwargs:hidden_sizes', [(32, 32)], 'hid')
    eg.add('ac_kwargs:activation', [torch.nn.ReLU], '')
    eg.add('pi_lr', [0.001])
    eg.add('clip_ratio', 0.3)
    eg.run(ppo_pytorch, num_cpu=args.cpu)
```

**My Jupyter Attempt**

I put all of the code from Custom_env.py in cell #1.
I then registered the environment in cell #2:

```
gym.register(
id='TEST-v1',
entry_point='__main__:Shell_Class',
max_episode_steps=200,
reward_threshold=25.0,)
```

based on this Q/A: [Register gym environment that is defined inside a jupyter notebook cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67087799/register-gym-environment-that-is-defined-inside-a-jupyter-notebook-cell)
, I make the environment in cell #3:

```
gym.make('TEST-v1')
```

and get this non-descriptive output:

> <TimeLimit<Shell_Class< TEST-v1 >>>

In cell #4, I tried to execute ExperimentGrid code directly within Jupyter like so:

```
from spinup.utils.run_utils import ExperimentGrid
from spinup import ppo_pytorch
import torch

num_runs=1
cpu=4
env_name='TEST-v1'
eg = ExperimentGrid(name='Jupyter-test')
eg.add('env_name', env_name, '', True)
eg.add('seed', [10*i for i in range(num_runs)])
eg.add('epochs', 500)
eg.add('steps_per_epoch', 4000)
eg.add('ac_kwargs:hidden_sizes', [(32, 32)], 'hid')
eg.add('ac_kwargs:activation', [torch.nn.ReLU], '')
eg.add('pi_lr', 0.001)
eg.add('clip_ratio', 0.3)
eg.run(ppo_pytorch, num_cpu=cpu)
```

The experiment starts up as usual but then runs into some kind of error:

```
> ================================================================================
ExperimentGrid [Jupyter-test] runs over parameters:

 env_name                                 [] 

    TEST-v1

 seed                                     [see] 

    0

 epochs                                   [epo] 

    500

 steps_per_epoch                          [ste] 

    4000

 ac_kwargs:hidden_sizes                   [hid] 

    (32, 32)

 ac_kwargs:activation                     [] 

    ReLU

 pi_lr                                    [pi] 

    0.001

 clip_ratio                               [cli] 

    0.3

 Variants, counting seeds:               1
 Variants, not counting seeds:           1

================================================================================

Preparing to run the following experiments...

Jupyter-test_test-v1

================================================================================

Launch delayed to give you a few seconds to review your experiments.

To customize or disable this behavior, change WAIT_BEFORE_LAUNCH in
spinup/user_config.py.

================================================================================
                                                                                
Running experiment:

Jupyter-test_test-v1

with kwargs:

{
    "ac_kwargs":    {
        "activation":   "ReLU",
        "hidden_sizes": [
            32,
            32
        ]
    },
    "clip_ratio":   0.3,
    "env_name": "TEST-v1",
    "epochs":   500,
    "pi_lr":    0.001,
    "seed": 0,
    "steps_per_epoch":  4000
}





================================================================================


There appears to have been an error in your experiment.

Check the traceback above to see what actually went wrong. The 
traceback below, included for completeness (but probably not useful
for diagnosing the error), shows the stack leading up to the 
experiment launch.

================================================================================



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-de843fd528cf> in <module>
     15 eg.add('pi_lr', 0.001)
     16 eg.add('clip_ratio', 0.3)
---> 17 eg.run(ppo_pytorch, num_cpu=cpu)

~/Downloads/spinningup/spinup/utils/run_utils.py in run(self, thunk, num_cpu, data_dir, datestamp)
    544 
    545             call_experiment(exp_name, thunk_, num_cpu=num_cpu, 
--> 546                             data_dir=data_dir, datestamp=datestamp, **var)
    547 
    548 

~/Downloads/spinningup/spinup/utils/run_utils.py in call_experiment(exp_name, thunk, seed, num_cpu, data_dir, datestamp, **kwargs)
    169     cmd = [sys.executable if sys.executable else 'python', entrypoint, encoded_thunk]
    170     try:
--> 171         subprocess.check_call(cmd, env=os.environ)
    172     except CalledProcessError:
    173         err_msg = '\n'*3 + '='*DIV_LINE_WIDTH + '\n' + dedent("""

~/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in check_call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    309         if cmd is None:
    310             cmd = popenargs[0]
--> 311         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    312     return 0
    313
```